# React Native Split Screen info

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Im trying to make an app that in a specific screen top half of it maintains the unchanged always with the same info and the bottom half of it has different button that when clicked it changes to various other screens being the top never changes and the bottom is different dependent of the choice made by the user

I tried doing this but what happen is an error saying "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"
and the code is:

This is the screen that i need to be spit in two

```
export const ProcessAnalysis = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <View style={[styles.row, styles.border]} className="w-full justify-around">
                <InfoText
                    title={'Número'}
                    description={'22/DSAVRLT/2023'} />
                <InfoText
                    title={'Data'}
                    description={'22/02/2023'} />
                <InfoText
                    title={'Estado'}
                    description={'Em apreciação'} />
                <InfoText
                    title={'Regional'}
                    description={'DSAVRLT'} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.column} className="m-2">
                <View style={styles.row} className="w-full justify-around mt-1">
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Data de factos'}
                        description={'22/DSAVRLT/2023'}
                        size={10} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Data'}
                        description={'20/02/2023'}
                        size={10} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Descrição'}
                        description={'Em apreciação'}
                        size={10} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Prescreve em'}
                        description={'DSAVRLT'}
                        size={10} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row} className="w-full mt-1">
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Observações'}
                        description={''}
                        width={'100%'} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row} className="w-full justify-around mt-1">
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Regime jurídico'}
                        description={'fff'}
                        width={'30%'} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Área'}
                        description={'ffff'}
                        width={'25%'} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Categoria'}
                        description={'fffff'}
                        width={'40%'} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row} className="w-full justify-around mt-1">
                    <InfoButton />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Motivo da prioridade'}
                        description={'ffff'}
                        width={'42%'} />
                    <InfoField
                        title={'Espécie animal'}
                        description={'fffff'}
                        width={'29%'} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View>
            <ProcessStack/>
            </View>
        </>
    );
};
```

and this how it is being made the process stack with all of the navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { FactsDescription } from '../screens/main/Process/FactsDescription';
import { MoreInfoButton } from '../screens/main/Process/MoreInfoButton';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const ProcessStack = () => {

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator  >
            <Stack.Screen name="MoreInfoButton" component={MoreInfoButton} />
            <Stack.Screen name="FactsDescription" component={FactsDescription} />
            {/*TODO Rest of screens*/}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

and just for testing this are the screen that are supposed to show

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

```
export const FactsDescription = () => {

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
};
```